# RewriteCond in .htaccess file gives me bad flag delimiters

Tags: .htaccess, rewrite, rewritecond

I'm upgrading a website and I use this .htaccess file to show maintenance page:

```
#MAINTENANCE-PAGE REDIRECT
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^127\.0\.0\.0 # Bogus IP address for posting here
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^127\.0\.0\.0 # Bogus IP address for posting here
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/maintenance\.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.no/maintenance.html [R=307,L]
```

This opens the maintenance page for all users except the two IP addresses I've added.
They get an `Internal Server Error`. I've used thesame script on another site, and that worked fine.

Looking at the error log, I see the following:

```
/var/www/vhosts/mysite.no/httpdocs/.htaccess: RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters
```

If I remove my .htaccess file, I can work with my site just fine.

My site is hosted on a VPN using CentOS 5.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have to use the `[OR]` flag to chain rules like this:

```
#MAINTENANCE-PAGE REDIRECT
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^127\.0\.0\.0 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^127\.0\.0\.0 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/maintenance\.html$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.no/maintenance.html [R=307,L]
```

In the apache docs, it's at the bottom of this section as an example: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

Also, you can use the `RewriteLog` and `RewriteLogLevel 3` directives to possibly gain some more insight.

Comment: Thanks, you led me to the answer. Actually it was the # comment behind the two lines that caused the error. Not sure why. But removing these fixed it.

Comment: @Steven: I belive line-end comments were once supported but since around Apache 1.3.22 they were removed. Full line comments only.

Answer (score 0):

Some things to try/check:

- Make sure `mod_rewrite` is loaded and enabled in apache.
- Make sure the `FileInfo` override is allowed (with `AllowOverride`) for `.htaccess` files.
- Remove the comments from your `RewriteCond` lines.